# How to efficiently handle bulk model saves in flask, sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, orm, bulk

I'm using flask, sqlalchemy. For example, I have the following model

```
class B(model):
    name = charfield

class A(model):
    name = charfield
    b = fk

    def save(self, ...):
        self.b.name = some_random_string
        self.b.save()
         self.super().save()
```

And I bulk update the A model as follows.

```
for a in A.query.all():  
   a.name = 'foobar'  
   a.save() # Here the associated model B is also updated.
```

However, this is not efficient, as we have to query the DB every time we make a save(), which is time consuming. We considered methods like sqlalchemy's bulk_update_mappings, but it is difficult to keep track of overridden save() methods and create the right set of objects, and it is also difficult to maintain the code to be consistent with the overridden save() internal logic. E.g. Whenever the save() method is changed, the bulk_update logic needs to be updated as well.

Is there an efficient way to do this, e.g.

```
for a in A.query.all():
    a.name = 'foobar'
    a.save() # No communication with the db here.
db.session.commit() # This is where we flush and commit all the object changes we made in the for                                   #loop above (not just updates to model a, but to related models) to the db at once.
```

To recap, we want to efficiently update a large number of objects in model A, but we want to keep the logic inside the overridden save() method consistent, meaning we want to keep everything that happens in the save() of model A without immediately reflecting it in the DB, and then reflect it all at once later.

Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Are you familiar with the terms "lazy loading" vs. "eager loading"?

Comment: @Gord Tompson yes I know

Comment: Do you come from a Django background? The example code (charfield, save()) looks like Django code.  Also, how many rows does "bulk" mean?

Comment: Also, what is in `super().save()`?

Comment: Yeah, I come from django. I handle almost 100k rows. In save(), I have db.session.add(self), and db.commit()

Comment: SQLAlchemy ORM defaults to lazy loading. Your query retrieves the A objects and you loop through them. When you refer to the related B object it triggers a lazy load of the attributes for that object. That's why your code hits the database on each iteration of the A list. If you change your query to use eager loading then you'll retrieve the related B information along with the A attributes and your code won't have to perform the subsequent select queries for each B. Details in the docs [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/relationships.html).